# How to group lists by common elements?

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a requirement to group similar lists. lets say below is my request:

```
<mainlist>
    <lista>
    <lista>
    <listb>
    <lista>
    <lista>
    <listb>
</mainlist>
```

lista and listb are lists with some fields in it. I want all lista in new list and same for listb as well.

Comment: See any `group-by` example, for instance in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping-examples and use e.g. `<xsl:template match="mainlist"><xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="node-name(.)">...</xsl:for-each-group></xsl:template>`

Comment: <xsl:variable name="pendinglist">
   <xsl:for-each select="$resultList/PendingPaymentList"/>
   <xsl:sort select="initiationDate" order="descending"/>
   <xsl:if test="not(position() > 100)">
   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:if>
  </xsl:variable>

will this gonna work to list the pendinglist seperate from resultList and sort them and limiting them to 100

Comment: I am afraid I don't see the relationship between your original question and the code snippet in your comment. You might want to ask a new question with properly edited and formatted code samples.